# Polinomios en visusla basic

Tags: vba

Como generar un código que me capture en un texbox un polinomio, no importa el tamaño, luego le ingrese una variable y lo evalúe, ejemplo: polinomio
4x^2+5x-3;=>
4(variable)^2+5(variable)-3 = variableresult

Comment: Bienvenido Luis Podrias [edit] la pregunta y mostrar el codigo que tienes ya

Comment: Bienvenido Luis. Además del código, estaría bien si pudieras añadir cual es el resultado esperado con un ejemplo. Entiendo que quieras que resuelva el polinomio, ¿no?